# Minimal API return result with StatusCode and Problem

Tags: c#, minimal-apis

The convention in our microservices is to return the result as follows:

```
    return result.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.Created
        ? StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result.MessageCode)
        : Problem(result.MessageCode, statusCode:result.StatusCode);
```

So making use of the StatusCode and Problem in Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc class ControllerBase.

We're adding a new microservice and figured we'd try to implement it as a Minimal API.
Is there an equivalent for the Minimal API that follows the same structure?

Comment: I don't think there's a built in way but you can probably write such a thing quite easily yourself

Comment: Yes, you can return `Results.StatusCode(...)` and `Results.Problem(...)`

Comment: The methods `Problem()`, `OK()`, `NotFound()` construct the relevant Result objects, eg `OKResult` or `BadRequestObjectResult`.  You can construct these objects directly or use the `Results.` convenience methods

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not quite, the `Results` class gives you `IResult` types, these are not the same as the normal MVC `OKResult`/`NotFoundResult` types, and the two things cannot be mixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`Results`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results?view=aspnetcore-7.0) class in minimal APIs. Here's an example.

Map the endpoint:

```
app.MapGet("getsomething", MyHandlerMethod);
```

And the actual method:

```
public IResult MyHandlerMethod() 
{
    var result = ...;

    return result.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.Created
        ? Results.StatusCode(result.StatusCode)
        : Results.Problem("Problem!) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost wat I was looking for. 
`return result.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.Created
        ? Results.StatusCode(result.StatusCode)
        : Results.Problem(result.MessageCode, statusCode:result.StatusCode) ;`.
I would have liked to have the option for the same parameters for `Results.StatusCode`

Comment: @LorenaSfăt [Results.Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.problem?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-http-results-problem(system-string-system-string-system-nullable((system-int32))-system-string-system-string-system-collections-generic-idictionary((system-string-system-object)))) does have the same parameters

Comment: Yes, but I see `Results.StatusCode` doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Starting with [**aspnet core 2.1**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-2.2#problem-details-support), dotnet added the [**`ProblemDetails`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails) class as a standardized way for APIs to report errors, based on the [RFC 7807](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7807).
Starting with [**aspnet core 7.0**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-7.0#new-problem-details-service), the preferred way to return problem detail objects from your controller actions is via [**`TypedResults.Problem`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.problem).

In your action just return the following:

```cs
return TypedResults.Problem("Hey", statusCode: StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity);
```

[image: TypedResults.Problem]

**Note** that the content type is `application/problem+json` in the response header.  You can use this to detect and then consistently deserialize error details which will always have a `type`, `title`, `status`, and `detail` property (per the spec) as well as extra fields the api might have sent back for extra info.

**By comparison**, here are other methods to return *just* a status code OR a status code and a plain text response body

[image: TypedResults.StatusCode and TypedResults.UnprocessableEntity]

**Note** that we we just return [`TypedResults.StatusCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.statuscode) that the body is empty. When using the [`TypedResults.UnprocessableEntity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.typedresults.unprocessableentity) helper method, you get a status code and can add a detail to the body, but it's just plaintext and doesn't offer much in the way of standardization and extensibility.

#### Further Reading

- [Use the TypedResults API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api#use-the-typedresults-api)
- [TypedResults vs Results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/responses#typedresults-vs-results)
- [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors)